# CakePHP - table naming convention

Tags: php, cakephp, naming-conventions

I'm really trying to understand CakePHP's naming conventions and the following isn't entirely intuitive to me.

Let's say I have two pieces of information:

videos - specific information about video
category - list of categories with id, title, description

How would I structure my tables? My first instinct is:

videos
categories
video_categories

Is this right?

Comment: It is worth noting that `video_categories` will work just fine, if you use a little bit more configuration. I, for example, prefer it over the convention `categories_videos`, as it is more clear what belongs to what. But always try to go with conventions first, and only strive from them, if it makes sense to do so afterwards and if you can decide that with more then intuition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be:

- `videos`
- `categories`
- `categories_videos` (plural model names in alphabetical order for HABTM)

If your videos can only belong to one category, forgo the `categories_videos` table and just put a `category_id` field into the `videos` table.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: Broken link... here's the one for version2.x http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#